# Aplicando função apply em um dataframe do pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Eu tenho um código (CÓDIGO01) que calcula as médias móveis (21 períodos) de uma determinada ação (individual) da bolsa de valores
(IBOV - B3). Dai eu criei um laço for onde ele determina q uma ativo esta em tendência de alta apos 6 altas seguidas das médias móveis
(hipótese, haja vista que existem mais váriaveis para se determinar isso).

Porém, eu quero fazer esse loop para mais de um ativo, no caso o CÓDIGO02, ou seja, ele aplicar uma função em cada coluna do meu código
e me retornar apenas o nome dos ativos que estão em tendência de alta (no caso, o nome da coluna). Eu tentei transformar o loop for em uma função e aplicar essa
função usando o "apply" do pandas em cada coluna (axis=1, tentei tbm axis='columns'). Só que estou tendo erro na criação da função. Quando eu executo a função usando
o apply aparace a mensagem "ValueError: Lengths must match to compare". Como posso corrigir isso?

Grato pela atenção.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mpl_dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 

#Nome do Ativo
ativo = 'WEGE3.SA'
acao2 = ativo.upper()

#Data de Início e Fim da Análise
inicio = '2020-1-1'
fim = '2021-1-27'

#CRIANDO O DATAFRAME C MEDIAS MOVEIS DE 21/72 PERIODOS
df_bolsa = wb.DataReader(acao2, data_source='yahoo', start=inicio, end=fim)

df_bolsa.index.names = ['Data']
df= df_bolsa.copy(deep=True)
df['Data'] = df.index.map(mdates.date2num)

# Médias Moveis
df['ema21'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=21, adjust=False).mean()
df['ema72'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=72, adjust=False).mean()

#DF DE PLOTAGEM
df1=df
df2=df[-120:]

#REGRA TENDENCIA
alta=1
for i in range(6):
  if(df2.ema21[-i-1] < df2.ema21[-i-2]):
    alta=0

baixa=1
for i in range(6):
  if(df2.ema21[-i-1] > df2.ema21[-i-2]):
    baixa=0

if (alta==1 and baixa==0):
  a1 = ativo.upper()+ ' EM TENDÊNCIA DE ALTA'
elif (alta==0 and baixa==1):
  a1 = ativo.upper()+ ' EM TENDÊNCIA DE BAIXA!'
else:
  a1 = ativo.upper()+ ' EM LATERALIZAÇÃO'
  
#PLOTAGEM DOS RESULTADOS
print("---------------------------------------") 
print(a1)
print("---------------------------------------")

ohlc = df[['Data', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]

f1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))

# plot the candlesticks
candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc.values, width=.6, colorup='green', colordown='red')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))

label_ = acao2.upper() + ' EMA26'
label_2 = acao2.upper() + ' EMA09'
ax.plot(df.index, df1['ema21'], color='black', label=label_)
ax.plot(df.index, df1['ema72'], color='blue', label=label_)

ax.grid(False)
ax.legend()
ax.grid(True)

plt.title(acao2.upper() + ' : Gráfico Diário')
plt.show(block=True)

#CÓDIGO02

#PERÍODO DE AVALIAÇÃO
inicio = '2020-1-1'
fim = '2021-1-27'

#LISTA DOS ATIVOS
ativos = ['SAPR11.SA','WEGE3.SA']

#GERAÇÃO DO DATAFRAME
mydata = pd.DataFrame()
for t in ativos:
    mydata[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start=inicio, end=fim)['Close']
df2 = mydata

#CÁLCULO MÉDIAS MÓVEIS
df3 = df2.apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=21).mean())

#GERANDO A FUNÇÃO
def trend(x):
  tendencia_alta=1
  for i in range(6):
    if(df3.columns[-i-1:] > df3.columns[-i-2:]):
      tendencia_alta=0

  print()
  if(tendencia_alta==1):
    print('TENDÊNCIA DE ALTA')
  else:
    print('TENDÊNCIA DE BAIXA')

#TENTANDO APLICAR A FUNÇÃO EM CADA COLUNA DO DF3
df3.apply(trend, axis=1)´´´
```

Comment: Dentro da função `trend` você deveria usar o `x` que está sendo recebido por parâmetro e não o df3 além disso, a função deveria retornar alguma coisa...